# VS.NET 2005 Form Designer - Can pages inherit their size from a parent, and can I see it in VS designer view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I have a group of pages I want in the same size.
I want to be able to change the page size in the designer view of visual studio,
and that all the other inheriting pages size will change.

I am currently working with VS.NET 2005 Form Designer

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write a parent form whose size is set in the designer, and a child form that inherits from the parent form. This works as expected in VS 2008, and the interface even supports a way to add a new "Inherited Form" from the file menu. However, I'm not sure if this is also the case in VS 2005.